# How to pass variable using click event

Tags: javascript, variables, scope

I am a "self learning entusiast" so asking some basic questions here. I now understand variable scoping but not clear on why it works here with the .each method but not the click. All I want to do is click on an element and use its value/text/attribute elsewhere outside of the click function.

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    abc = "";
    gsd = "";

    $("p").each(function() {

        if($(this).text() === "5") {
         abc = $(this).text();
         alert(abc);
        }
        })


    $("p").on("click", function() { 
         var gsd = $(this).text();
         //alert("this is abc: " + abc);
    })

 alert("this is from the each function" + abc);// this works
 alert("this is from the click function" + gsd); // this doesn't





})
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what is going on here, but it looks the second code is hit before the click event is fired from someone clicking on the event. What I recommend is maybe creating another function and then calling that inside the click event function:

```
function alertTextChange(e/*the event*/){
    gsd = $(this).text();
    alert("this is from the click function" + gsd);
}
$p.click(alertTextChange);
```

Answer (score 0):

Apart from re-declaring your variable gsd, it only gets set once you click on one of the p tags.  And because the alert happens before you can click, it doesn't set gsd.

I just added

```
alert(gsd);
```

within the click event.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/m4QJV/)

Answer (score 0):

Initially you have `gsd` outside of the scope, however inside of the function you are re-declaring the variable with `var`. Once the variable has been declared, to assign a value, you simply reference the variable name, no need to prefix with `var`. A quick example:

```
var x;

function doStuff(y) {
    x = y; //x is now set to the value of y, it's already declared above, no need for: var
    console.log(x);
}
```

Comment: sorry, that was a mistake on my part. i corrected that but still can not get the variable outside of the click function.

Comment: You're alerts are tripping before the click event. Obviously this is going to be undefined. Add the alert in the click event (or console) and try again. I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

A couple things:

1) You need to declare your variable with a "var" at the top of the function and not reuse "var" later in the click event:

```
var abc = "";
var gsd = "";
```

2) Your click function doesn't deliver which "P" element is being clicked. One way would be to alter how you're setting the event and reporting it to the function:

HTML: `<p id="pElem1" onclick="clickMe(this.id)">Click Me</p>`

jQuery:

```
function clickMe(p){
    alert('This is from the P element' + p);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`.each()` acts similar to a regular `for` loop. It follows the flow of the program. The `.on('click')` event handler, on the other hand, is attached to an event. The callback will be called *only* when the event is fired. It doesn't fire just because you attached it.

The confusing bit here is probably the use of callback functions. While both of the code samples use callbacks, they are used differently. You can think of the first one as a regular `for` loop where that callback is called each iteration. The second one's function gets called whenever the event is triggered, which is probably after the rest of your code runs.

A different problem here is scope. In the callback function, you re-define `gsd` in the scope of the callback function:

```
var gsd = $(this).text();
```

This `gsd` isn't the global `gsd`. This one is local to the callback function. Remove the `var` and `gsd` will once again refer to the global variable with that name.

Comment: so, whatever I want to do following the click event must take place within that function?

Comment: I follow you on the differences between the .each callback and the .click callback. And I see now that the alert fires before the click so that makes sense too. I see my mistake of redeclaring gsd inside the function, although that did not change the outcome. So I am still left with the same question, is there a way to access the global variable gsd following the click?

Comment: @user2232681: Exactly. You're only binding the event handler with that code, so the code that prints out `gsd` fires immediately after you *bind* the event handler, not trigger it. Put the `console.log()` inside of the click callback and it'll behave like you intend.